# CGI Buffering issue

Tags: c, cgi

I have a server side C based CGI code as:

```
cgiFormFileSize("UPDATEFILE", &size);   //UPDATEFILE = file being uploaded
cgiFormFileName("UPDATEFILE", file_name, 1024);
cgiFormFileContentType("UPDATEFILE", mime_type, 1024);
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

if (cgiFormFileOpen("UPDATEFILE", &file) != cgiFormSuccess) {
    exit(1);
}
output = fopen("/tmp/cgi.tar.gz", "w+");

inc = size/(1024*100);
fptr = fopen("progress_bar.txt", "w+");    
while (cgiFormFileRead(file, b, sizeof(b), &got_count) == cgiFormSuccess)
{
    fwrite(b,sizeof(char),got_count,output);
    i++;
    if(i == inc && j<=100)
    {
     fprintf(fptr,"%d", j);
     fflush(fptr);
     i = 0;
     j++;   // j is the progress bar increment value
    }
}
fclose(fptr);
cgiFormFileClose(file);
retval = system("mkdir /tmp/update-tmp;\
                 cd /tmp/update-tmp;\
                 tar -xzf ../cgi.tar.gz;\
                 bash -c /tmp/update-tmp/update.sh");
```

However, this doesn't work the way as is seen above. Instead of printing 1,2,...100 to  progress_bar.txt (referred by fptr)one by one it prints at ONE GO, seems it buffers and then writes to the file.
fflush() also didn't work.

Any clue/suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you know is not writing one by one?

Comment: How do you know it does it in one go? With no artificial delays inside the loop, this will run to completion almost immediately.

Comment: I didn't understant what you are trying to do, and what was the expected result. Please give more info.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know this. Thanks. But at the same time I couldn't find a suitable answer to my questions.

Comment: @Am : Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951732/file-upload-progress-bar . Just look at the server side code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, open the file before the loop and close after it ends. Too much IO.

The problem is here `w+` - this truncates your file. use `a+`. ([fopen](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fopen.html) help)

Comment: I tried that as well. Open the file before loop and close it after the loop, it doesn't work either. I do not want to append data, I want to update data every time that's why I used w+

Comment: To print the value at the start of file every time, however in this case this is not necessary as file open and close are done everytime.

Comment: ok, so u expected the end result to be that file containing "99"?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* writing it one-by-one, it's just that it does it so fast that you're vanishingly unlikely to ever see the file with a value other than 99 in it.

This is easily demonstrated if you put a `sleep(1)` within the loop, so that it's slow enough for you to catch it.

Comment: It does so (i tried sleep(1);), however not at the point desired. Once CGI has done copying data,and writing to the text file; after that it prints to text file.

Comment: What makes you think that `cgiFormFileRead()` is called slowly, as the file uploads? It appears far more likely that the uploaded file is buffered completely and then provided to your CGI.

Comment: You are right, something this kind is happening. However, I didn't understand "cgiFormFileRead() is called slowly, as the file uploads" Do you have any idea what should I try now